# How to get all the collection documents using SwiftMongoDB?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, swift2

I've installed SwiftMongoDB using CocoaPods. Added 2 documents in the collection. When I try to retrieve them using .find() method It only returns one document.

```
func all() -> [MongoDocument]{
    let UsersCollection = MongoCollection(name: "users")
    mongodb?.mongodb.registerCollection(UsersCollection)

    for (index,value) in UsersCollection.find().successValue!.enumerate(){
        debugPrint(value)
    }

    // UsersCollection.find().successValue!.count 
    // returns 1.

    return UsersCollection.find().successValue!
}
```

My collection looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bb29ca42b9b41900000000"), "address" : "US", "given" : "User", "birthDate" : "1985-08-01", "family" : "UserFam", "identifier" : "E3826", "date" : "10.2.2016 at 14:15:6" }{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bb29ca42b9b41900000000"), "address" : "US", "given" : "User2", "birthDate" : "1985-08-01", "family" : "UserFam2", "identifier" : "E3826", "date" : "10.2.2016 at 14:15:6" }
```

Is there another way of getting all the documents? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. Maybe the package is in it's early versions ....

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SwiftMongoDB but I have used swift for iOS development and mongoDB with Java. First of all, here is your first object's and your second object's ids together:

```
1st: 56bb29ca42b9b41900000000
2nd: 56bb29ca42b9b41900000000
```

As you can see they are the same. So I strongly believe your issue arises from that. Have you defined that property as **primary key**?